# Issue with design mode: Migrated ASP.net web application framework 1.1 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2003

We have migrated a web application from Visual Studio Framework 1.1 to Visual Studio 2010. The migration has been successfull, but when we try to open each page in designer mode, all the controls are throwing error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

When we run the application all the controls are loading properly in the browser.

Is there any solution to resolve this error when we open the aspx page in design mode? Or is it fine to continue with this error as the application is working fine?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the readability. Try to use smaller and clear sentences and paragraphs. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your codebehind file.

```
protected override void OnInit( EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInit(e);
   if(!this.DesignMode)
   {
      // place code here for dynamic control creation
         TextBox txtUserName = new TextBox();
         txtUserName.ID= "UserID"  ;
         usersPlaceholder.Controls.Add(txtUserName);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.these are not dynamic controls.added this code but its not working.